# What is the best time to set resolution-based lengths?

Tags: java, optimization, processing

This question will use Processing 3+ code syntax.

Say I have a class `Bullet` that spawns at a Player's x position at a set height.

```
class Bullet
{
    int x;
    int y = player.y;
    int w = SIZE_X / 150;
    int h = SIZE_Y / 50;

    Bullet()
    {
        x = player.x;
    }

    void display()
    {
        rect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

Say I'm using this `Bullet` class to spawn a bullet in my Space Invaders game. In `SpaceInvaders.pde` I'll create a `Player` class that represents my ship. This `Player player` has a `player.x` and `player.y` component. So, when in `SpaceInvaders.pde` I call `player.shoot()` I will create a new `Bullet` in an `ArrayList<Bullet> bulletList`.

I'm wondering what the best time is to set certain variables to make sure my computer does as little computation as possible.

Right now I can think of three ways of setting this up:

Like in the code above.

Or:

```
// In SpaceInvaders.pde:
int BulletYPos = player.y;
int bulletWidth = SIZE_X / somenumber; 
int bulletHeight = SIZE_Y / somenumber;
// where SIZE_X / SIZE_Y represent the size of the sketch

// in Class Player:
class Player
{
    // <snip ... >

    void shoot()
    {
        new Bullet(x, BulletYPos, bulletWidth, bulletHeight);
    }
}
`
// in class Bullet:
class Bullet
{
    int x, y, w, h;

    Bullet(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        w = _w;
        h = _h;
    }

    void display()
    {
        rect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

That would certainly mean `SIZE_X / somenumber` would only be calculated once. But, I could also see it being much slower because of the increase in cycles where the computer's assigning values.

Basically my question kind of comes down to:

If I'm saying `int y = player.y` in `class Bullet`, does it get calculated ONCE, or every time a new Bullet class is made?

My understanding is that the code in the `Bullet` class's constructor `Bullet()` gets run each time that a new `Bullet` is instantiated. But does that mean it's not determining my `int y, w, h` each time, and does that just once at program launch? Or is it secretly also being called each time I create a new instance of the `Bullet` class?

Comment: Is there a max number of bullets on screen at the same time? Instead of creating a new bullet every time, you could use a library of bullets, and skip this aspect of your problem.

Comment: Do you search for [`static`](https://processing.org/reference/static.html)?

Comment: If you want to read on the subject, the [object pool design pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-pool-design-pattern/) is what I was just speaking about. I can elaborate on the subject if needed, but the tl;dr is: you have a "pool manager" which will either give an available object, or create a new one if needed, so you only create the minimum amount of the said object.

Comment: Whilst I'm thankful of your notes here, I don't think they're answering my question at all. 
This is a hypothetical situation. I'm just interested in the hypothetical difference between CPU cycles. Just curious as to see what would be the utmost efficient way to create objects with resolution based lengths like this. I'm not saying that's the way you should code it, I'm saying I'm interested in the computer science behind it.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, these lines are only running once:

```
int bulletWidth = SIZE_X / somenumber; 
int bulletHeight = SIZE_Y / somenumber;
```

These lines will run every time you create a new instance of the `Bullet` class:

```
Bullet(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h)
{
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    w = _w;
    h = _h;
}
```

These lines will also run every time you create a new instance of the `Bullet` class:

```
class Bullet
{
    int x;
    int y = player.y;
    int w = SIZE_X / 150;
    int h = SIZE_Y / 50;
```

The values are not recalculated every time you use them.

Note that you can test this yourself using functions. Try something like this:

```
int sketchX = getSketchX();

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Bullet b = new Bullet();
  }
}

int getSketchX() {
  println("getSketchX");
  return 42;
}

class Bullet {
  int classX = getClassX();

  public Bullet() {
    int constructorX = getConstructorX();
  }

  int getClassX() {
    println("getClassX");
    return 42;
  }

  int getConstructorX(){
    println("getConstructorX");
    return 42;
  }
}
```

Taking a step back, I would say that you're probably worrying too much about performance. If you haven't done any benchmarking, you shouldn't be going out of your way to make sure your computer does as little computation as possible. Doing some basic math for each bullet is not going to cause any problems. (Compare that to how much your computer has to do to draw the screen, and you'll see what I mean.)

There's a famous quote: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) This means that you shouldn't worry too much about optimizing your code if you haven't even measured your code yet.

If you measure your code and find out that the `Bullet` constructor is indeed taking too long, then you can go ahead and worry about it. But you'll find that your program spends much more time drawing things than it does dividing two numbers.

To answer your question: the best time to set resolution-based lengths is **wherever is the most readable**.

The most readable location depends on how the different pieces of your code fit together in your brain. And like many things in coding, it's a tradeoff: putting the initialization at the top of your sketch might make sense if you have a lot of constants that will not change, but putting the initialization inside the `Bullet` constructor might be more readable if you might change the size of each bullet in the future. There isn't a single "best" place to put your code.

Comment: Very helpful insights!
I do wholeheartedly agree that I shouldn't be worried too much about stuff like this. But, this was a question out of pure interest, not out of necessity. 

I'm not going to start writing all my code this way, because I'm fine with sacrificing performance increments like this in a simple Processing sketch, as my computer will most likely be able to just run the sketch anyway. 
But, I am interested which way would need the least amount of CPU cycles. Because even though you're skipping math by calculating the values only once, you still have to pass them to new vars.

Comment: @KamielDev Hopefully I answered that question in the top half of my answer, and you can confirm using code like I posted. Variables are **not** recalculated when they're used as the **value** in an assignment to another variable, but you are copying the value to the new variable, which will use up memory.

Comment: I'm sorry I might have to elaborate a little then. 

I understand that if I you declare ```int i = 2 + 1``` it'll just do ```2+1``` once when assigning ```int i``` to a value. Then if you call  ```i``` later it reads ```3```
However, what I was wondering is if, each time you create a new instance of ```Bullet``` the variables outside of ```Bullet()``` will be re-assigned, once, again. 

Or, if only the variables inside of ```Bullet()``` do this and the variables in ```Bullet``` but outside of ```Bullet()``` get assigned only once on the creation of the very first instance of ```Bullet```?

Comment: The variables outside of `Bullet` are only calculated once. You can confirm this by running the code I posted above.

Comment: I know that, haha. I mean the variables inside of ```Bullet``` but outside of ```Bullet()```.. Please see https://hastebin.com/sofezarexu.cpp

Comment: Isn't that the `classX` variable in my code example? If not, can you add a similar print statement yourself?

Comment: I just tried out your code and it is.
So, that answers part of my question. Apparently it doesn't matter if you assign them in ```Bullet``` or ```Bullet.Bullet()```; so I guess it doesn't store a sort of template for ```Bullet``` that it can re-use. 

However, then I'm still interested in whether predetermining them in your ```main``` file and then passing them to ```Bullet``` using a constructor function would cost less CPU cycles than calculating them in ```Bullet()``` each time.

Comment: I think the best way to answer these questions is to put together a little example program that tests it out. If the calculation is expensive, then calculating it once and passing that value into the constructor will avoid repeating that calculation multiple times, but how much that "saves" depends on how expensive the calculation is.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I just wanted to ask whether anyone has done this before or knows the answer from their CS course. If that leads nowhere, I'll try and get my hands dirty if I'm still interested... haha